# appcompat_v7 error when new android application created

Tags: java, android, eclipse

1) So far whenever I create android project, I get a java main class which extends activity, and an XML file... that's it, but now after recently upgrading my android eclipse, whenever I create a project the main java file extends action bar activity instead of just activity and a fragment class is also created with the XML file, and on top of all this a new folder appcompat_v7 gets created automatically with red cross as an indication of error over it, I am new to android development and all this stuff stopping me from continue, as I do not know why all this is happening and how can I tackle this problem.

2) When a project is created i get this error message in my console:

[appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users...\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache

Any suggestions on how solve such problems and what is wrong with my android eclipse highly appreciated

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/15/really-blank-activity-why-appcompat-shoved-down-your-throat.html

Comment: @CommonsWare, Why not just set the minimum target SDK to something else when you create a new project? http://i.stack.imgur.com/KKrHC.png

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue in the new android sdk update 22.6.2
This library is automatically added to all the projects which you create.

To eliminate this process, you can either roll back to a previous version of update or you can just remove all the unnecessary contents from the project like deleting the library and copying the code from fragment.xml to activity.xml.
Also delete the fragment related code from the MainActivity.java

Comment: No, it is added to all *activities* you create. If you create a project and uncheck the "create activity" checkbox, it will not add the extra libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this as you have upgraded your Eclipse IDE. This library exist as a library project in your Eclipse workspace. Each project you create gets its own appcompat_v7 library which accompanies it. If you do not use appcompat in your project, feel free to delete the corresponding library and the dependency in your project config.It allows you to use ActionBars of Android. So if you want to use ActionBar, you need AppCompat. If you have a project that does not use action bar, then you do not need the appcompat_v7 library folder that is created.
You can delete the files of fragment from Src folder and from layout also and can do simply as you did.You can remove it by right click on your project-> properties->Android->select appcompatV7->remove.
Hope it will help you out..